# The boundary of this set is piecewise smooth?

Tags: gn.general-topology, differential-topology

Consider a sequence of open sets in $R^n$: $\Omega_1 \supset \Omega_2 \supset\cdots$.  Consider that this sets are  bounded, convex with the boundary piecewise smooth .When i say smooth i  mean $C^{\infty}$

I believe that the set $\operatorname{int}\left(\,\overline{\bigcap \Omega_i}\,\right)$ have the boundary piecewise smooth . but i have no idea to how to prove this ...
Someone can give me a help to prove or disprove this?

thanks in advance

Comment: This is obviously not true, already in dimension 2. Start with a compact convex region $K$ whose boundary is not piecewise smooth, then take $\Omega_i$ to be a $C^\infty$ open convex set containing $K$ and contained in the $(1/i)$-neighborhood of $K$, that is, $K\subset\Omega_i\subset K+B(1/i)$, where $B(1/i)$ denotes the open ball of radius $1/i$. Their intersection is $K$, though each of $\Omega_i$ has a smooth boundary.

Comment: I meant to say $K+B(1/(i+1))\subset\Omega_i\subset K+B(1/i)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can assume that $\Omega_{n+1}$ is strictly contained in the interior of $\Omega_n$ for all $n$, there is no reason to assume that the boundary of the limit has any interesting properties. Perhaps you are missing an hypothesis.

In any case, perhaps the following construction will give you food for thought.

Work in $\Bbb{R}^2$. Consider graphs of concave functions over $[0,1]$. The regions beneath these graphs are convex, and if $f\geqslant g$, then the region beneath $f$ is contained in the region beneath $g$. We define the sequence $(g_n)$ of functions over $[0,1]$ inductively by:

1) $g_0(t) = -t$ if $0\leqslant t<1/2$; and

$g_0(t) = t-1$ if $1/2\leqslant t\leqslant 1$.

2) for all $n$, given $g_0,...,g_n$, $g_{n+1}$ is defined by:

$g_{n+1}(t) = g_0(t) + g_n(2t)/2$ if $0\leqslant t<1/2$; and

$g_{n+1}(t) = g_0(t) + g_n(2t-1)/2$ if $1/2\leqslant t\leqslant 1$.

Observe that $-1\leqslant g_n\leqslant 0$ for all $n$, and the sequence $(g_n)$ converges to a continuous nowhere differentiable function.

For all $n$, let $f_n$ be such that $f_n''=2g_n$, $f_n(0)=f_n'(0)=0$. $f_n$ is a decreasing family of non-positive concave functions bounded below by the function $f_n(x)=-x^2$. The limit $f_\infty$ is a concave function which is nowhere $C^3$. In particular, it is not smooth.

Answer (score 1):

Your $\overline{\bigcap\Omega_i}$ can be an arbitrary convex compact $C$. By induction on $i$, we construct $\Omega_i\subset\Omega_{i-1}$. For a suitable $0<\varepsilon_i<\frac1i$, an open $\varepsilon_i$-neigbourhood of $C$ is contained in $\Omega_{i-1}$. We take finitely many open $\varepsilon_i$-balls centred at points of $C$ that cover $C$, and let $\Omega_i$ be the convex hull of the union of these balls. It is easy to show that the boundary of $\Omega_i$ is piecewise smooth. As there are convex compacts $C$ with the boundary of their interiror not piecewise $C^\infty$ (for example, take $n=2$ and a couple of graphs of convex but not $C^\infty$ functions suitably placed in ${\mathbb R}^2$), the desired fact is not true.